# Passing Object over activities using putSerializable

Tags: android, bundle, android-activity

I'm trying to pass my dbhelper instance from one activity to another using this code

```
    private void onCategoriesClick() {
        private DbAdapter db;
        db = new DbAdapter(this); 
        Intent i = new Intent(this, CategoriesActivity.class);
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        b.putSerializable("db", db); //geting NullPointerException here
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

DbAdapter class implements `Serializable`

I'm geting confused, could anybody point my mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do what you're trying to do but to answer your question, a new `Intent` doesn't have any 'extras' so `Bundle b = i.getExtras();` wont return anything, i.e., `b` will be `null`. An `Intent` only has 'extras' if you put them there. Simply use `i.putExtra("db", db);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getExtras() returns null, because you haven't put any extras into the Intent before you call it.  This means that b == null, hence the NPE.  Just put the serializable in the intent directly.

```
i.putExtra("db", (Serializable) db);
```

In general, though, avoid passing serializables over intents if you can help it.

Answer (score 3):

Create the dbhelper in the activity that will use it. If you really must pass it between activities, it would be much simpler to store it in a static variable (in your application class for easy access)

Comment: My mistake was to getextras instead putextras but this is important clue here. Why is it better to create new dbhelper in each activity instead of passing same object between them? P.S. I love your app Kuffs :)

Comment: It isn't a set rule but in general, the less dependencies an activity has on external objects, the easier it is to maintain. Imagine a database being passed around various activities. If one activity decides to close the database, the others could suddenly fail as they were expecting the database to be available and connected.